# Composer require symfony fork

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I need to use Symfony fork for testing bugfix. My `composer.json` is:

```
{
    ...
    "repositories": {
        "symfony": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/nicolas-grekas/symfony.git"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        ...
        "symfony-bundles/redis-bundle": "2.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "1.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.*",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "3.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

(Full code is here: [Github](https://github.com/strider2038/symfony-fork-example/blob/fork/composer.json))

Running commands such as

- `composer require symfony/symfony "dev-cache-fix"`
- `composer require symfony/symfony "dev-cache-fix as 4.2.1-dev"`

Fails with error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for __root__ dev-fork -> satisfiable by __root__[dev-fork].
    - symfony/symfony dev-cache-fix conflicts with __root__[dev-fork].
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony dev-cache-fix as 4.2.1-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[dev-cache-fix].
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I need to delete all Symfony components (except monolog-bundle, because it is outside of fullstack framework), clean composer options `conflict` and `replace`. After that I need to change version of `behat/mink` to `dev-master` because the latest stable verion 1.7.1 locks `symfony/assets` component to version `3.x` (issue [github/minkphp](https://github.com/minkphp/Mink/issues/771)). And the final step was to enable all used components in `config/packages/framework.yaml`.

```
framework:
    validation:
        enabled: true
        enable_annotations: true
    assets:
        enabled: true
    serializer:
        enabled: true
        enable_annotations: true
    annotations:
        enabled: true
    property_info:
        enabled: true
```